# Simplifying Go Code

Tags: go

I have two functions as shown below which look similar, but using different functions to query the db. Since Go doesn't encourage overloaading methods, is the redundancy acceptable? Or should I refactor them into one function? All comments are welcomed.

```
var getCustomers = func() ([]customer, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

var getCustomerById = func(int64) (*customer, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func listCustomer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *appError {
    cus, err := getCustomers()
    if err != nil {
        return &appError{err, "No customer found", 404}
    }

    res, err := json.Marshal(cus)

    if err != nil {
        return &appError{err, "Can't display record", 500}
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, string(res))
    return nil
}

func viewCustomer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int64) *appError {
    cus, err := getCustomerByID(id)
    if err != nil {
        return &appError{err, "No customer found", 404}
    }

    res, err := json.Marshal(cus)

    if err != nil {
        return &appError{err, "Can't display record", 500}
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, string(res))
    return nil
}
```

Suggestion to use -1 to list all customer, but I'm not sure if this is the best it can be:

```
func viewCustomer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int64) *appError {
    var c *customer
    var clist []customer
    var err error

    if id < 0 {
        clist, err = getCustomers()
        res, err := json.Marshal(clist)

        if err != nil {
            return &appError{err, "Can't display record", 500}
        }

        fmt.Fprint(w, string(res))
        return nil
    } else {
        c, err = getCustomerById(id)
        res, err := json.Marshal(c)

        if err != nil {
            return &appError{err, "Can't display record", 500}
        }

        fmt.Fprint(w, string(res))
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put both in one function. All IDs are valid? for example, if only positive ID are valid, using -1 as ID can be used to change the behavior.

Comment: By the way, this is not exclusive of Go. I would try to do the same even if you could overload the function.

Comment: I think it's OK to dupe because it's not much code (or tricky code). But the -1 trick suggested by @siritinga is fine with me too.

Comment: @siritinga I was thinking about the same thing, but I'm not able to make it simplest, please see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since Go doesn't encourage overloaading methods, is the redundancy acceptable? Or should I refactor them into one function?

The answer to your question depends heavily on the real code and your task. If listing one customer is very different from listing several customers (that is, you need different information and have different presentation logic), I'd say that duplication here is not that bad, since the difference may grow larger in the future, so a DRY solution could turn into an `if` and `switch` mess quickly. (I've had a similar experience on a non-Go project and since then I think that DRY is good but you should not be fanatic about it.)

On the other hand, if you're making, say a JSON API, you could make it more DRY. Define your `getCustomers` function like this:

```
func customers(ids ...int64) ([]customer, error) { /* ... */ }
```

This way you can:

- call it like `customers()` and get all customers;
- call `customers(42)` and get a customer whose ID is 42;
- call `customers(someIDs...)` and get multiple customers by their IDs.

All can be done in one handler in a straightforward way.

> All comments are welcomed.

Two nitpicks on your code:

- Getter methods in Go are idiomatically named `foo` and not `getFoo`, so I used `customers` in my example. You would most probably call it as `DB.Customers(ids...)`, so it looks a lot like a getter method.
- What's up with `var foo = func()` notation? Unless there is a reason for that (like using these functions as closures), I'd suggest sticking with the `func foo()` notation, since it's more idiomatic and generally easier to `grep`. **EDIT:** as OP pointed out in the comments, another case for `var foo = func()` notation is of course functions that can be faked in testing, as shown in Andrew Gerrand's [Testing Techniques talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndmB0bj7eyw).

I hope that helps.

Comment: woah, it's you again to clear my doubts! Totally accepted your answer. Will be refactoring my codes shortly. regarding `var foo = func()`, I did that so that in my tests, I can change `foo` to return dummy data, without relying on injections. I tried not to use injections because I'm currently developing a webapp with net/http only (don't really like frameworks). Well, at least that's what I know for now.

Comment: @AlvinThen I completely forgot about fakable functions even though I use them in my code. I will edit my answer to include this case.